# Perform call to Microsoft Graph Api for Intune approveApps

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am working on automating Intune to perform the Managed Google Play Application approvals, the API documentation I have been referencing is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-androidforwork-androidmanagedstoreaccountenterprisesettings-approveapps?view=graph-rest-beta

Requirements for approveApps is almost identical to syncApps:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-androidforwork-androidmanagedstoreaccountenterprisesettings-syncapps?view=graph-rest-beta

I can make the call to syncApps successfully but approveApps returns BadRequest. The only difference between the calls appears to be the body requirements.
It needs packageIds as a String collection and approveAllPermissions as a Boolean.

Please help me to successfully make a post to https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/androidManagedStoreAccountEnterpriseSettings/approveApps

Minimum Reproducible Code:

```
    var authHeader = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    };

    var appApprovePostData = JSON.stringify({
      packageIds: ["com.bundle.example"],
      approveAllPermissions: true
    });

    var appApproveOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      uri:
        "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/androidManagedStoreAccountEnterpriseSettings/approveApps",
      headers: authHeader,
      body: appApprovePostData
    };
    response = await request(appApproveOptions);
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so we can help you figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application needs to be prefaced with "app:".  So, in your example, you need

```
var appApprovePostData = JSON.stringify({
  packageIds: ["app:com.bundle.example"],
  approveAllPermissions: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of thoughts -

1. If you get back a RequestID, can you post that?
2. Can you compare the request body submitted by the Azure Portal (F12 developer mode to get the request body trace) for the same app approval with your request body generated from code?

Dave

Comment: The RequestID: 7d8bdf62-5bca-4fe6-9b8a-d19908a730ac

Comment: Azure Portal Does not appear to use Graph API to make the call to approve. It seems to call a google batch request that is not exactly human readable.